# couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.core' in rails 4 while trying to change design look of the datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datatable

This is the application.css

```
*= require bootstrap

*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
*= require admin/taluks
*= require bootstrap-submenu.min
```

This is the application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap-submenu.min
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require data-confirm-modal
//= require admin/taluks
//= require admin/ceos
//= require admin/progress_charters
//= require admin/societies
//= require turbolinks
```

This is the gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise'
gem "cancan"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'data-confirm-modal', github: 'ifad/data-confirm-modal'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

I tried downgrading jquery-rails to 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0". But it's not helping. I restarted server. Cleaned  assets and cleaned bundle

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue than you right now with the latest version of query-ui-rails. I suppose that you followed the railscast on datable, if so then I invite you to  the query-rails-ui Github. The rails cast is a bit outdated.

Now if you want to include specific module you would have to write:

```
*= require jquery-ui/core
*= require jquery-ui/theme
```

Comment: Yes , I was following rail cast.. I will try ur solution and get back to you. Thanks a ton